# Entity Framework 6 filter the data you access

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have an application which access users and some of their's permission. Those are stored in tables which are used by other applications as well, so it would be disastrous to change anything which would be related to other apps. For instance, if I were to say "User X's permission are R/W on my app" I would not want User X's other applications permissions to disapear.

Is there a way to filter things in such a way ?

**Pseudo Data**

- Permission 1 : UserX, ReadRight, ApplicationA
- Permission 2 : UserY, WriteRight, ApplicationA
- Permission 3 : UserX, WriteRight, ApplicationB
- Permission 4 : UserX, ReadRight, ApplicationB

**Application A, pseudo code**

```
UserX.Permission = [ { WriteRight, ApplicationA }, { WriteRight, ApplicationA } ]
Save UserX
```

**Resulting pseudo Data**

- Permission 1 : UserX, ReadRight, ApplicationA *-- Cool, I meant that*
- Permission 5 : UserX, WriteRight, ApplicationA *-- Cool, I meant that*
- Permission 2 : UserY, WriteRight, ApplicationA
- <strike>Permission 3 : UserX, WriteRight, ApplicationB</strike> *-- Oops!! I didn't mean to delete that.*
- <strike>Permission 4 : UserX, ReadRight, ApplicationB</strike> *-- Oops!! I didn't mean to delete that.*

**Note:**

The business nature of Application/User/Permission is not relevant, it could also be  Tree/Farmer/Fruit (If I set the number of fruits of a tree, and it has 5, it doesn't mean Farmer only has 5 fruits)

Comment: It's not clear. Can you please add more details? And describe better other apps and their access rights on the data.

Comment: Not getting it either. Can you provide something that resembles EF? For example, `var app_A_Permissions = context.Permissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == "UserX" && p.Application == "ApplicationA");`

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](http://entityframework-dynamicfilters.net/)

This library allows you to filter data for a specific user.

```
modelBuilder.Filter("NotesForCompany", (Note n, int orgID) => n.Person.OrganizationID==orgID, (MyContext ctx) => ctx.CurrentOrganizationID);
modelBuilder.EnableFilter("UserOrg", (MyContext ctx) => !ctx.UserIsAdmin);
```